# Show partial view depends on the calling Action and Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

As every one know that by default there is a layout page
 when you create project in mvc3 , and also there is a
 partail view which comes by default named `_LogOnPartial.cshtml`
 where login and logout links are availble and it renders on layout page .
I want that when i call home page which is inherited from layout , then
 those login and logout links not show on home page
  ......
 In short i don't want to render `_LogOnPartial.cshtml` when i call home page .

Comment: What problem did you face? In other words, _What have you tried?_

Comment: problem is this that , every page is inherited from layout page and logonpartial is rendered on layout . Thus it comes on every page but i don't need it on some page

Comment: You can put an `if` surrounding the PartialView call in the layout depends in the Action.

Comment: but how would i know that my desired page is called or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] != "Foo" &&  
     ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] != "Bar")
{
    // call the partial you want here.
}
```

Comment: @Ahsan. Yes, but what's wrong with what I wrote? Hardcode URL isn't the MVC way.